# Updating CSV rows in Java

Tags: java, csv, filewriter

I have a CSV. Through Java, I am trying to manipulate it.

Let me illustrate through an example - 
 My CSV looks like this :

```
Deepak, Freddy, 123
Green, Which, 456
Reddy, Bluish, 789
Yellowish, Irish, 987
Green, Which, 765
```

What I want to do here is - because there are two entries with same value in column one - Green. I want to append the "765" to the second row like "Green, Which, 456, 765" .

I could not find any package in Java, which can update or replace any row of a CSV . Is there any other way of doing this ?
I am able to do this by creating another CSV and copying the contents of original CSV after manipulating its rows.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want to append with a comma?  It is pretty unusual to have a CSV that allows for an unlimited number of columns.  Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, I want to append with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), IIRC there's something there that will help you.

Comment: I have used opencsv, but I could not find any method that will update or replace any row.